# Maria DB AWS Create Update After trigger

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.5

I would like to update processed value when the update happens on a row. If the processed <> 0 then update processed=1 else processed=0

Syntax error...

SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 1

My code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER users_after_update
AFTER update ON users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF NEW.processed <> 0 THEN
  UPDATE users SET new.processed=1;
 ELSE 
  UPDATE users SET new.processed=0;
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Tried without delimiters? BTW do you really want to UPDATE ALL processed records?

Comment: I just want to modify the newly update column's processed value. Code edited.

Comment: Sorry misread that - you cannot alter NEW. values after update and you cannot action the table which fired the trigger. Perhaps a before trigger might be what you want and it would help if you could provide sample data and expected outcome as text

Comment: Example:
Table
First name,last name, city, processed
If an update happens on a row and processed is not 0 i would like to setup it to 1.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER users_after_update BEFORE UPDATE
ON users
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.processed=1

This one works...

CREATE TRIGGER users_after_update BEFORE UPDATE
ON users
FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.Processed <>0  THEN
SET NEW.processed=1
END IF;

This one doesn't work...

Comment: Any particular reason for not sharing the exact error message you got from your last try? I really don't like guessing...

Comment: Your first trigger in your last comment contains a single statement and does not need delimiters or begin..end Your second trigger in the last comment contains more than one statement and DOES NEED delimiters and begin..end. Also I would check if any column is updating before setting processed